# Why Foursquare Api not Responding according to Categories filter?

Tags: ios, foursquare

[Foursquare Api with Query](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?locale=en&price=&client_secret=YTYXPHGIQBXFOTUHSGCHUB5CXQZPIY4PHJFYUEPW2FMDRRRY&ll=51.599340803492,-0.337448380887508&llAcc=0.0&alt=0.0&sortByDistance=1&v=20140503&client_id=3UNNIWKNSGJWQ3YINXI3SWX5DI3G3NFNWBTRXMFXWBXSERVX&query=Strip%20Club,Adult%20Boutique,Erotic%20Museum&altAcc=-1.0&intent=&m=foursquare&venuePhotos=1)

As per above link , i am using foursquare and passing categories in query as Strip Club,Adult Boutique, Erotic Museum .. and in response i m getting some irrelevant results like for Bushey Country Club which is under Golf Courses category , i can't figure out why foursquare returning result outside passed categories as query , any1 can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Explore API can't be a good choice for filter venues category.you can use Search API with category id filter. for example, this API return nightlife category venue at Vilnius to you  http://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=54.6872,25.2797&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06376d81259